# How to add javascript header to node js built index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, build, twitch

So I'm trying to make a working React app into a Twitch Extension (I don't need any twitch integration).

The only thing to make it work with Twitch's iframes is add a tag in the html file

```
<script src="https://extension-files.twitch.tv/helper/v1/twitch-ext.min.js"></script>
```

And another call of javascript code on startup that uses stuff from that twitch-ext.min.js file

```
window.Twitch.ext.onAuthorized(function(auth) {
  console.log('The JWT that will be passed to the EBS is', auth.token);
  console.log('The channel ID is', auth.channelId);
});
```

What im currently doing is running ***npm build*** then manually editing the generated index.html and main.xxxxx.js to include those lines of code in the optimized minified files. This obviously seems a bit inefficient and I feel like there must be a way to tell node that during build it should include these lines. So is what I'm asking possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got an answer from someone who knew about Node. What you do is edit the index.html and index.js file that your react app should have.

The ***npm run build*** actually uses those 2 files to generate the minified built files so I just added

```
<script src="https://extension-files.twitch.tv/helper/v1/twitch-ext.min.js"></script>
```

to index.htmla
and my

```
window.Twitch.ext.onAuthorized()
```

call in the index.js file and it all worked.

You can find index.html in the public folder of your react project if you used *npx create-react-app*. And index.js is in the src folder.